# Keep getting this fatal error in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, main-activity

This is my first time using Android Studio, but I have used Eclipse and Xamarin for android before. But when I open the main_activity.xml, there's no "visual" and no option to select one. I also get the fatal error that says this:

Here's the error:

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.jetbrains.android.actions.AndroidRunSdkToolAction.actionPerformed(AndroidRunSdkToolAction.java:40)
        at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionPopupStep$1.run(PopupFactoryImpl.java:733)
        at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup$18.run(AbstractPopup.java:1258)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushRequest(FocusManagerImpl.java:641)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushNow(FocusManagerImpl.java:622)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushIdleRequests(FocusManagerImpl.java:592)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.access$200(FocusManagerImpl.java:59)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$IdleRunnable.runEdt(FocusManagerImpl.java:107)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.EdtRunnable$1.run(EdtRunnable.java:28)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Sorry it's long, I don't know what it means though. I tried deleting and reinstalling the sdk, that didn't work though.

Comment: The thing you need to figure out is if it is your install that is broken or your project.  Try editing your .xml file as text to fix any issues with it and then see if you can build the project.  Or try building a known-good sample project.

Comment: Try "File -> Invalidate caches and restart" or something like that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I haven't done anything in my project yet. I just went straight to the visual editor and got that error. Xamarin has been acting up today too when I try to go to the visual editor.